# FFmpeg: HLS options cannot be set/get/find

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg

We are using `FFmpeg` libraries `git-ee94362 libavformat v55.2.100`.
We are trying to write a simple `HLS` code example based on `muxing.c` standard one.
Let be two input streams, video and audio (they can be synthetic, doesn't matter). 
Our purpose is to `mux` them into `M3U8` playlist using `HLS`. 
Suppose, duration of every TS segment file be 3 sec, and the desirable maximum number of entries in `M3U8` output file be 100.

From the `FFmpeg` application sources, one can see that the Apple HTTP Live Streaming segmenter implemented in `hlsenc.c` file. 
And the relevant options there are, as well: `"hls_list_size"`, `"hls_time"`, etc.
The problem is that we have not succeeded to set/get/find these options in a conventional way, as shown in the following code:

---

```
// Here is a part of main() program

int64_t i1 = 0;
void *target_obj;

AVFormatContext *ofmt_ctx = NULL;
AVOutputFormat *ofmt = NULL;

avformat_alloc_output_context2(&ofmt_ctx, NULL, NULL, "Example_Out.m3u8");

ofmt = ofmt_ctx->oformat;

// The relevant options ("hls_list_size", "hls_time") are located under ofmt->priv_class->option.
// But AVClass *priv_class is not the first member of the AVOutputFormat.
// So, due to the documentation, av_opt_find...(), av_opt_get...() and av_opt_set...() 
// cannot be used for options within AVOutputFormat.
// In practice, any of the following three lines causes exception.
const AVOption *o = av_opt_find2(ofmt, "hls_list_size", NULL, 0, AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN, &target_obj);
av_opt_get_int(ofmt, "hls_list_size", AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN, &i1);
av_opt_set_int(ofmt, "hls_list_size", 10, AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);
```

---

Our question: If there is a way to overcome the problem, i.e. to set/get/find options for `AVOutputFormat`, like for `AVCodecContext` (for example)?

Thank you,

Andrey Mochenov.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing in the priv_data field of AVFormatContext (ofmt->priv_data) instead of the struct itself. It will be NULL at this point in your code but it gets filled in after a call to avformat_write_header.

av_opt_set_int(ofmt->priv_data, "hls_list_size", 10, AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN) should work at that point.

If the options need to be set before calling avformat_write_header() like your options for Live Streaming, you should pass them as the AVDictionary** options argument to that function.

Comment: In this case the private class is already allocated by avformat_alloc_output_context2, so av_opt_set can be safely called before avformat_write_header.